# What is the time complexity of comparing 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Can someone please explain what the time complexity of the operation `d1 == d2` will be where d1 and d2 are 2 python dictionaries

Comment: A dictionary can contain an arbitrarily complex structure. The worst case can not be determined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**: If the two dictionaries have the same number of items, it takes *O(n)* equality checks with *n* the number of items. If the two dictionaries have a different number of items, then it takes *O(1)*, since then the two dictionaries are different. Note that the equality checks can be computationally expensive.

---

A problem with estimating the time complexity here is that a dictionary can contain values like lists, other dictionaries, trees, etc.

Take for example the following two dictionaries:

```
{ 1: [1,4,2,5] } == { 1 : [1,4,2,6] }
```

Here both dictionaries have the same key, but in order to check if the lists are the same, it will, worst case, take time linearly with the size of the list.

We can however speak in terms of the number of comparisons we need to do. That will be *O(n)* with *n* the number of elements of the two dictionaries if we assume the dictionary has constant lookup time.

We can check in the [`CPython` source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L2647) in the `dict_equal(PyDictObject *a, PyDictObject *b)` function.

The function will first check if the two dictionaries contain the same number of objects. If that is not the case, then of course the two dictionaries can not be equal.

Next we can iterate one of the two dictionaries. For each key/value pair in the first dictionary, we look up if such key exists in the second dictionary. If no such value exists, then we know the two dictionaries are not equal, and thus we can return `False`.

If such key exists, we perform an equality check between the corresponding value of the first dictionary and the second dictionary. If the comparison fails, we can return `False`, since that means the two dictionaries have a key for which the corresponding values are different.

If for all the keys of the dictionary, the key exists in the other dictionary, and the values are considered the same, we can return `True`, since that means all keys are present in the other dictionary, and their corresponding values are the same as well.

Comment: I think O(n) is correct for average case. Correct me if I am wrong but I think worst case scenario is O(n^2). Assume both dictionaries are of length n and we iterate over all keys in  dictionary A  and check if that key and value exists in dictionary B. There is a chance that the key exists in dictionary B but there exists a collision such that two keys with different values have the same hash. So  there is a chance we may check all keys in dictionary B.

Comment: @vi_ral, well I made a small typo: "*We can however speak in terms of the number of comparisons we need to do. That will be O(n) with n the number of elements of the two dictionaries if we assume the dictionary has **constant** lookup time*.". The claim *O(n)* deals with the *number* of *equality checks*. The lookup can depend on how a bucket is implemented, some implementations use a *binary tree*, but ragardless linear lookup is very scarce, especially since the hashing offset is normally set each time different when the Python interpreter starts running.